# javascript and google map, coordinates in array not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this select wich gets the coordinates database:

```
<select id="zona" onchange="initialize()">
```

By choosing an option I get values such as:

```
36.488487091208526, -4.882313608398476
```

In the function I separate the coordinates and display the map like this:

```
function initialize() {
   var z = document.getElementById("zona").value;
   var x = z.split(", ");
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(x[0],x[1]);
 }
```

Then I want to use the values for the marker, however it does not work, I get as error that the value is not a number:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: x[0], lng: x[1]},
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is cause marker need float:

```
 var value1 = parseFloat(x[0]);
 var value2 = parseFloat(x[1]);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: {lat: value1, lng: value2},
```

Solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks a lot @Fabio Venturi Pastor
I print the position like this as I need like this and it works:
  `code` position: {lat: value1, lng: value2},`code`

Comment: Im glad it helps you,  can you put my answer as correct please?

Comment: Already did, searched for it, and my son told where it was. Thanks again @Fabio Venturi Pastor

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried    ?
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatlng}),

Comment: I need the values separate, however below worked, Thanks for trying to help